# Deleted etc/apache/sites-available/default

Tags: apache, dns

I have just deleted etc/apache/sites-available/default (apache config file) which had around 140 subdomains. Is there any method to undelete this file, because all sites working properly until apache will be restart, so config file must be saved somewhere in cache.

Comment: This is why you alias your delete commands to mv to some regularly flushed directory... If you don't have backups, you're kinda effed...

Comment: If you actually don't have backup, use some data recovery software.

Comment: Yes I have backup, just wondering, where is this file in cache that everything working properly.

Comment: The file is read into memory at server startup.